# Javascript in photoshop - Trying to understand a script found here to customize it - Layer hide/display

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm trying to modify a script I found here so it would randomly display 1 layer per group in some but not all of the groups, with some condition. I have roughly 1hr into Javascript and do not understand 1 thing in the script I found before delving deeper in the modification. Operator for means it'll execute the code multiple times, in this case once for each group of layer. The function Save() is called within this "for" operator.

At the same time, the Visible() function is called multiple time already, once for each pattern you asked for in the initial prompt.

```
function Visible() {
  var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets; // loops through all groups
  for(var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++){
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible=true;
    var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;
    var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);
    groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;
    Save();
  }
  Revert();
}

function Save() {
  var outFolder = app.activeDocument; // psd name
  var outPath = outFolder.path;
  var fName = "PNG";   // define folder name
  var f = new Folder(outPath + "/" + fName);
  if ( ! f.exists ) {
    f.create()
  }
  var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName +"/" + "Pattern_" +  num + ".png");
  pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
  pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;
  app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
}


function Revert(){
   var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID( "Rvrt" );
   executeAction( idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO );
}

var count = prompt("How many patterns you want","");
for (var x=0 ; x<count;x++){
  var num = x+1;
  Visible();
}
```

From my basic understanding, it means that the file will be saved and overwritten for each new group of layer found and used in the Visible() function? Therefor, if I have 5 group of layers, it'll be saved 5 time before the final version of the image is completed and should instead be moved outside of the "for" operator, if I understood correctly. Would it be better if instead written this way?

```
function Visible() {
  var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets; // loops through all groups
  for(var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++){
    var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;
    app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible=true;
    var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;
    var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);
    groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;
  }
  Save();
  Revert();
}
```

Comment: Reading the save() code, `var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName +"/" + "Pattern_" +  num + ".png");` it will save out a .png from the source .psd. By putting the save outside the loop - you'll lose that and it will only save once. Also, if you are new to Photoshop scripting, avoid using groups until you're ready for them.

Comment: Grouping is not really that hard for the simple project I am trying. Figuring out how to effectively rule out some groups if 1 is drawn is harder, but I am slowly learning and getting there!

Now, thanks for clearing this up! I still have a hard time understanding how it would save only once. Do you think you'd be able to explain what I am reading wrong?

What I see:

Comment: Function name Visible() will be called "count" time, depending on the input.

Initial code will call the Save() function each time a new group of layer is made visible in the loop, until all groups are gone thru this visible() function loop. If there is 6 groups and initial "count" is 10, the save function will be called 6 times during the first Visible() call, and this will repeat 9 other times, for a total of 60 saves.

Sure, the end result of each Visible() function is a save with all layer enabled, but didn't the Save() function operate for nothing 5 out of 6 time?